# What is the use of PHP Callbacks?

Tags: php, callback

I want to know that when should we use PHP Callback functions and what are the benefits of using PHP Callback functions instead of traditional functions?

For example

**Traditional way** of getting name in lowercase

```
<?php
function string($string){
    $results = array(
        'upper' => strtoupper($string),
        'lower' => strtolower($string),
    );
    return $result;
}
$name = string('Ahmar');
echo $name; //Output: ahmar
?>
```

Getting the same output using **Callbacks**

```
<?php
function string($string, $callback){
    $results = array(
        'upper' => strtoupper($string),
        'lower' => strtolower($string)
    );
    if(is_callable($callback)){
        call_user_func($calllback, $result);
    }
}
string('Ahmar', function($name){
    echo $name['lower']; //Output: ahmar
});

?>
```

Kindly explain that what is the benefit using closure callbacks and when should we use it?
Thank you

Comment: That function does not output that result…!?

Comment: I was just thinking that.. it will return an array not a string.. and an array to string error surely.. upon further reading that first function is a total fail, first learn php, then worry about callbacks and lambdas

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 6):

There's little use in PHP for callbacks which will be called *when an action has completed*, e.g.:

```
string('Ahmar', function ($name) { echo ... })
```

This is very idiomatic in languages like Javascript; but that is because Javascript has a rather different mode of execution than PHP does. In Javascript many things are usually happening at once, either in the browser due to an interactive UI, or on the server due to many parallel requests. PHP though operates in a single thread non-interactively, so there aren't many parallel tasks happening that need to be coordinated asynchronously. Parallel execution in PHP happens through different PHP instances, not within the same PHP instance.

In Javascript you need callbacks to coordinate what should happen when something that's happening in the background has finished processing:

```
foo(bar => {
    // this happens after
});

// this happens before
```

In PHP the same is achieved simply by waiting for the function to return:

```
// this happens before
$bar = foo();
// this happens after
```

(Note that there are of course exceptions to that; e.g. when writing a web socket server in PHP, you'll get the same callback based architecture you'd see in node.js.)

So for the most part you use callbacks when you need to pass not just a value as a parameter to an algorithm, but a block of code. As a concrete example, take `usort`:

```
usort($foo, function ($a, $b) { return $a['bar'] - $b['bar']; });
```

This callback has nothing to do with asynchronous execution, but is for passing a custom sorting logic to a function.

Comment: "(Note that there are of course exceptions to that; e.g. when writing a web socket server in PHP, you'll get the same callback based architecture you'd see in node.js.)" If you are using non-blocking sockets and streams in PHP that is.

Comment: Well, yes, you won't get that "for free". Just saying you *can* write asynchronous-ish code in PHP. It's just that you have to bend over backwards to some degree to do so, while it's the default MO for languages like JS.

Comment: It is just like working with tools... Do you get a screw in the wood with a hamer or screwdriver.. Both tools can or should work but the screwdriver is designed to do it more properly the hamer isn't designed for that so it might get you in some trouble.. Motto of the story pick the right tool

Comment: Right. Quite honestly I don't understand all the things people have grafted onto PHP over the years when oftentimes it would have been easier to use a language better suited for the job. But oh well, language inertia is a thing I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

closures are functions that return functions. The returned function is an Anonymous function which can then be assigned to a variable and passed in as a callback. One of the advantages of using closures is that the parent function can perform or keep track of certain attribute defined on the parent function, and even have access to that information if needed, and you can implement the closure however you want, that all depends on how the function is defined and instantiated.

Imagine you have an e-commerce website where your users have a limited amount of credit and you want to limit or warn the user when they reach the limit, we can implement that like the following:

```
class UserCredit
{
    public static function creditLimitWarn($amount){
        $total = 0;
        $creditlimit = $amount;
        return function($purchase) use (&$total,$creditlimit){
            $total += $purchase;
            if($total > $creditlimit){
                echo "Purchase above credit limit:\nYour credit: $creditlimit.\nYour current purchase $total\n";
            }
        };
    }
}

$user = UserCredit::creditLimitWarn(3000);
$user(5000);



// Output:
// Purchase above credit limit:
// Your credit: 3000.
// Your current purchase 5000
```

Then you can register the $user as a callback for other class or a method, probably in the class where the purchases are processed.

As you can see, closures are really powerful, the problem is to know where to implement them and noticing a good place where implementing a closure will save a lot of lines of code and probably bring some performance gain for your application

Comment: Functions that return functions are called *higher order functions.* Closures aren't functions that return functions (not necessarily at least). Closures are a special kind of function, you could say "closureness" is a specific behaviour of a function.